# I dont get why unity gives a compile error here

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I'm trying to change the text of a TMPro text box, but unity reports at 20,79 I need a }. I put in the bracket and 11 errors pop up. debug pls? I don't know much c# myself so I can't do it myself. pls, help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class tetxmeshpro : MonoBehaviour
{ int previoushealth = 100;
  private TextMeshProUGUI textMesH;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        var Player; GameObject;
        textMesH = GetComponent<TextMeshProGUI> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if ((Player.GetComponent(playerScript).Health)) not == previoushealth;)
        {
            previoushealth = Player.GetComponent(playerScript).Health;
            textMesH = previoushealth;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What exactly is

   ```
   var Player; GameObject;
   ```

   supposed to do? ;)

   It seems you rather mean

   ```
   GameObject Player;
   ```

   Either way the `Player` is not a field so later in `Update` you don't have access to it either. You probably rather wanted a

   ```
   [SerializeField] private GameObject Player;
   ```

   on class level so you can reference your object in it. Or even better give it the correct type right away:

   ```
   [SerializeField] private playerscript player;
   ```

   This way you don't need the `GetComponent` later.
2. What is this

   ```
   if ((Player.GetComponent(playerScript).Health)) not == previoushealth;)
   ```

   This is `c#` not some Shell/Dos script -> use `!=` and not `not ==`. Also `if` conditions don't end with a `;` and there is a `)` too much. And also `GetComponent` either is generic, then it is `GetComponent<T>()` or you pass in a type but then you have to cast it like `((T)GetComponent(typeof(T)))`.

   If something it should rather simply be

   ```
   if (Player.GetComponent<playerScript>().Health != previoushealth)
   ```

Your class should rather look like

```
public class tetxmeshpro : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    int previoushealth = 100;

    // Link these via the Inspector using drag&drop 
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _textMesH;
    [SerializeField] private playerscript _player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        if(!_textMesH) _textMesH = GetComponent<TextMeshProGUI>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_player.Health != previoushealth)
        {
            previoushealth = _player.Health;
            textMesH = previoushealth;
        }
    }
}
```

Though, note that naming your class `textmeshpro` a) might lead to confusions with the existing `TextMeshPro` and also doesn't at all reflect the purpose of that class. I would suggest something like e.g. `HealthDisplay` or anything similar meaningful.

Comment: thanks for covering everything but you bamboozled me with half of what you said.